# j2me: Uncaught exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError (stack trace incomplete)

Tags: java, memory-management

I am creating a j2me game that has 10 levels, 2 coins, a staircase, background music, a monster and a set of spikes. when i get to the second level of the game i am this error, i no this becasue i am running out of memory.... is there anyway way i can improve my code below to prevent this error from happening or is there anyway i can fix this?

```
public class QuatschCanvas 
    extends GameCanvas 
    implements Runnable { 

/** 
 * @return the points 
* 
 * WHAT HAS TO BE DONE TO THE GAME 
 * fix the door bug for all the levels after level 1 
 * add 2 more coins 
 * make the coins appear and disappear at different times but in the same place 
 * add music to game 
 * add sound when you hit a wall or die 
 * add methods to fix up the code and make it look nice 
 * fix record store to highest score 
 * get game going back to main menu when finished 
 * add animation to the main menu 
 */ 
public boolean mTrucking; 
private LayerManager mLayerManager; 
private TiledLayer mAtmosphere, mBackground, mCollisionBackground, mCollisionDoor; 
private int mAnimatedIndex; 
private Sprite mQuatsch, mCoin,mCoin2, mMonster, mKey, mStairs, mSpikesUp, mSpikesDown; 
private Graphics graphics; 
Image gameOver, youWin; 
private static int mState, mDirection, dState; 
private static final int kStanding = 1; 
private static final int kRunning = 2; 
private static final int kRunningUp = 3; 
private static final int kRunningDown = 4; 
private static final int kCoinSpin = 5; 
private static final int kMonsterMoveUp = 6; 
private static final int kMonsterMoveDown = 7; 
private static final int kLeft = 1; 
private static final int kRight = 2; 
private static final int kUp = 3; 
private static final int kDown = 4; 
private static int lives = 3; 
private static int coins = 0; 
private static int points = 0; 
public static int currentLevel = 1; 
public static int countForLevels = 0; 
private static int keys = 0; 
private static final int[] kRunningSequence = {0, 1, 0, 2}; 
private static final int[] kStandingSequence = {0}; 
private static final int[] kRunningSequenceUp = {3, 4, 3, 5}; 
private static final int[] kRunningSequenceDown = {6, 7, 6, 8}; 
private static final int[] kCoinSpinning = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 
private static final int[] kMonsterDown = {0, 1, 2, 1}; 
private static final int[] kMonsterUp = {9, 10, 11, 10}; 
private static int infinateLoop, spikeLoop; 

public QuatschCanvas(String quatschImageName, 
        String atmosphereImageName, String backgroundImageName, String coinName, String monsterName, 
        String keyName, String stairsName, String spikesNameUp, String spikesNameDown) throws IOException { 
    super(true); 

    // Create a LayerManager. 
    mLayerManager = new LayerManager(); 
    int w = getWidth(); 
    int h = getHeight(); 
    mLayerManager.setViewWindow(96, 0, w, h); 

    createBackground(backgroundImageName, 0); 
    createAtmosphere(atmosphereImageName); 
    createQuatsch(quatschImageName); 
    createCoin(coinName); 
    createSecondCoin(coinName); 
    createMonster(monsterName); 
    createKey(keyName); 
    createStairs(stairsName); 
    createSpikesUp(spikesNameUp); 
    createSpikesDown(spikesNameDown); 

    gameOver = Image.createImage("/game-over.png"); 
    youWin = Image.createImage("/you-win.png"); 
} 

private void createBackground(String backgroundImageName, int level) 
        throws IOException { 
    // Create the tiled layer. 
    Image backgroundImage = Image.createImage(backgroundImageName); 

    mCollisionDoor = new TiledLayer(8, 7, backgroundImage, 96, 96); 
    mCollisionDoor.setPosition(12, 0); 
    for (int i = 0; i < doorMap[level].length; i++) { 
        int column = i % 8; 
        int row = (i - column) / 8; 
        mCollisionDoor.setCell(column, row, doorMap[level][i]); 
    } 
    mAnimatedIndex = mCollisionDoor.createAnimatedTile(8); 
    //mCollisionBackground.setCell(3, 1, mAnimatedIndex); 
    mLayerManager.append(mCollisionDoor); 

    mBackground = new TiledLayer(8, 7, backgroundImage, 96, 96); 
    mBackground.setPosition(12, 0); 
    for (int i = 0; i < map[level].length; i++) { 
        int column = i % 8; 
        int row = (i - column) / 8; 
        mBackground.setCell(column, row, map[level][i]); 
    } 
    mAnimatedIndex = mBackground.createAnimatedTile(8); 
    // mBackground.setCell(3, 1, mAnimatedIndex); 
    mLayerManager.append(mBackground); 

    mCollisionBackground = new TiledLayer(8, 7, backgroundImage, 96, 96); 
    mCollisionBackground.setPosition(12, 0); 
    for (int i = 0; i < collsionMap[level].length; i++) { 
        int column = i % 8; 
        int row = (i - column) / 8; 
        mCollisionBackground.setCell(column, row, collsionMap[level][i]); 
    } 
    mAnimatedIndex = mCollisionBackground.createAnimatedTile(8); 
    //mCollisionBackground.setCell(3, 1, mAnimatedIndex); 
    mLayerManager.append(mCollisionBackground); 


} 

private void createAtmosphere(String atmosphereImageName) 
        throws IOException { 
    // Create the atmosphere layer 
    Image atmosphereImage = Image.createImage(atmosphereImageName); 
    mAtmosphere = new TiledLayer(8, 1, atmosphereImage, 
            atmosphereImage.getWidth(), atmosphereImage.getHeight()); 
    mAtmosphere.fillCells(0, 0, 8, 1, 1); 
    mAtmosphere.setPosition(0, 192); 

    mLayerManager.insert(mAtmosphere, 0); 
} 

private void createQuatsch(String quatschImageName) 
        throws IOException { 
    // Create the sprite. 
    Image quatschImage = Image.createImage(quatschImageName); 
    mQuatsch = new Sprite(quatschImage, 48, 48); 
    mQuatsch.setPosition(96 + (getWidth() - 48) / 2, 100); 
    mQuatsch.defineReferencePixel(24, 24); 
    setDirection(kLeft); 
    setState(kStanding); 
    mLayerManager.insert(mQuatsch, 1); 
} 

private void createKey(String keyName) 
        throws IOException { 
    // Create the sprite. 
    Image keyImage = Image.createImage(keyName); 
    mKey = new Sprite(keyImage, 48, 48); 
    mKey.setPosition(250, 110); 
    mKey.defineReferencePixel(24, 24); 
    setState(kStanding); 
    mLayerManager.insert(mKey, 0); 
} 

private void createSpikesUp(String spikesNameUp) 
        throws IOException { 
    // Create the sprite. 
    Image spikesImageUp = Image.createImage(spikesNameUp); 
    mSpikesUp = new Sprite(spikesImageUp, 48, 48); 
    //mSpikes.setPosition(200, 110); 
    mSpikesUp.defineReferencePixel(24, 24); 
    setState(kStanding); 
    mLayerManager.insert(mSpikesUp, 0); 
} 

private void createSpikesDown(String spikesNameDown) 
        throws IOException { 
    // Create the sprite. 
    Image spikesImageDown = Image.createImage(spikesNameDown); 
    mSpikesDown = new Sprite(spikesImageDown, 48, 48); 
    //mSpikes.setPosition(200, 110); 
    mSpikesDown.defineReferencePixel(24, 24); 
    setState(kStanding); 
    mLayerManager.insert(mSpikesDown, 0); 
} 

private void createStairs(String stairsName) 
        throws IOException { 
    // Create the sprite. 
    Image stairsImage = Image.createImage(stairsName); 
    mStairs = new Sprite(stairsImage, 48, 48); 
    mStairs.setPosition(130, 520); 
    mStairs.defineReferencePixel(24, 24); 
    setState(kStanding); 
    mLayerManager.insert(mStairs, 0); 
} 

private void createCoin(String coinName) 
        throws IOException { 
    // Create the atmosphere layer 
    Image coinImage = Image.createImage(coinName); 
    mCoin = new Sprite(coinImage, 48, 48); 
    mCoin.setPosition(500, 150); 
    mCoin.defineReferencePixel(24, 24); 
    setState(kCoinSpin); 
    mLayerManager.insert(mCoin, 0); 
} 

private void createSecondCoin(String coinName) 
        throws IOException { 
    // Create the atmosphere layer 
    Image coinImage = Image.createImage(coinName); 
    mCoin2 = new Sprite(coinImage, 48, 48); 
    mCoin2.setPosition(250, 220); 
    mCoin2.defineReferencePixel(24, 24); 
    setState(kCoinSpin); 
    mLayerManager.insert(mCoin2, 0); 
} 

private void createMonster(String monsterName) 
        throws IOException { 
    // Create the atmosphere layer 
    Image monsterImage = Image.createImage(monsterName); 
    mMonster = new Sprite(monsterImage, 48, 48); 
    mMonster.setPosition(520, 500); 
    mMonster.defineReferencePixel(24, 24); 
    setDirection(kUp); 
    setState(kMonsterMoveUp); 
    mLayerManager.insert(mMonster, 0); 
} 

public void start() { 
    mTrucking = true; 
    Thread t = new Thread(this); 
    t.start(); 
} 

public void run() { 
    int w = getWidth(); 
    int h = getHeight(); 
    Graphics g = getGraphics(); 
    int frameCount = 0; 
    int factor = 2; 
    int animatedDelta = 0; 

InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/audio/mainsong.mp3"); 
Player p;  
    try { 
        p = Manager.createPlayer(is, "audio/mpeg"); 
        p.setLoopCount(-1); 
        p.start(); 
    } catch (IOException ex) { 
        ex.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (MediaException ex) { 
        ex.printStackTrace(); 
    } 






    while (mTrucking) { 
        // create timer for the dragon to move up the map 
        Timer aTimer = new Timer(); 
        TimerTask firstTask = new TimerTask() { 

            public void run() { 
                setDragonState(kMonsterMoveUp); 
                mMonster.move(0, -3); 
                mSpikesUp.setVisible(true); 
                mSpikesDown.setVisible(false); 
                mCoin.setVisible(false); 
                mCoin.setVisible(true); 
            } 
        }; 
        // create a timer for the dragon to move down the map 
        TimerTask secondTask = new TimerTask() { 

            public void run() { 
                setDragonState(kMonsterMoveDown); 
                mMonster.move(0, 3); 
                mSpikesUp.setVisible(false); 
                mSpikesDown.setVisible(true); 
                mCoin.setVisible(true); 
                mCoin.setVisible(false); 
            } 
        }; 

        // continueos loop so the dragon will keep moving up and down the map 
        if (infinateLoop >= 0 && infinateLoop < 50) { 
            aTimer.schedule(firstTask, 1000); 
            infinateLoop = infinateLoop + 1; 
            mMonster.nextFrame(); 
        } else if (infinateLoop >= 50 && infinateLoop < 100) { 
            aTimer.schedule(secondTask, 1000); 
            infinateLoop = infinateLoop + 1; 
            mMonster.nextFrame(); 
        } else { 
            infinateLoop = 0; 
        } 


        // what to do if the player hits a coin 

        if (mQuatsch.collidesWith(mCoin, true)) {         
            mCoin.setVisible(false); 
            coins++; 
            setPoints(getPoints() + 20); 
        } 

        if (mQuatsch.collidesWith(mCoin2, true)) { 
            mCoin2.setVisible(false); 
            coins++; 
            setPoints(getPoints() + 20); 
        } 

        if (mQuatsch.collidesWith(mStairs, true)) { 
            aTimer.cancel(); 
            firstTask.cancel(); 
            secondTask.cancel(); 
            countForLevels++; 
            if(countForLevels<10){ 

            for (int i = 0; i < map[countForLevels].length; i++) { 
                int column = i % 8; 
                int row = (i - column) / 8; 
                mBackground.setCell(column, row, map[countForLevels][i]); 
            } 
            for (int i = 0; i < collsionMap[countForLevels].length; i++) { 
                int column = i % 8; 
                int row = (i - column) / 8; 
                mCollisionBackground.setCell(column, row, collsionMap[countForLevels][i]); 
            } 
            for (int i = 0; i < doorMap[countForLevels].length; i++) { 
                int column = i % 8; 
                int row = (i - column) / 8; 
                mCollisionDoor.setCell(column, row, doorMap[countForLevels][i]); 
            } 
            mCollisionDoor.setVisible(true); 
            mKey.setVisible(true); 
            mCoin.setVisible(true); 
            mCoin2.setVisible(true); 
            mLayerManager.append(mBackground); 
            mLayerManager.append(mCollisionBackground); 
            mLayerManager.append(mCollisionDoor); 

            //resetItems(int bg_x, int bg_y, int s_x, int s_y, int k_x, int k_y, int su_x, int su_y, int sd_x, int sd_y, int m_x, int m_y, int c_x, int c_y) 
            if (countForLevels == 1) { 
                resetItems(-450, -300, -40, 40, 150, -70, -50, 228, -158, 180, 10000, 10000, -330, -170, -300, 70);//170 
            } else if (countForLevels == 2) { 
                resetItems(12, 0, 226, 315, 420, 300, 520, 144, 520, 96, 10000, 10000, 615, 115, 605, 515);//115 
            } else if (countForLevels == 3) { 
                resetItems(-450, -300, -330, 200, 150, -70, -230, -156, -230, -204, 10000, 10000, -330, -170, -300, -170); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 4) { 
                resetItems(12, 0, 606, 120, 420, 100, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 410, 344, 320, 330, 320, 300); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 5) { 
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -72, -332, 200, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, -137, 130, 150, -70, 100, -70);//mite be -115 n 300, 200 , 100 
            } else if (countForLevels == 6) { 
                resetItems(12, 0, 130, 505, 250, 110, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 410, 300, 615, 215, 605, 215); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 7) { 
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -175, -50, 200, -98, 228, -98, 180, 10000, 10000, -130, -170, -100, -170); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 8) { 
                resetItems(12, 0, 606, 215, 620, 425, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 520, 465, 620, 525, 660, 525); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 9) { 
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -175, 150, -170, -28, 228, -28, 180, 10000, 10000, -40, -40, -20, -40); 
            } 
            } 
        } 

        if (mQuatsch.collidesWith(mSpikesUp, true)) { 
            if (countForLevels == 1) { 
                resetItems(-450, -300, -40, 40, 150, -70, -50, 228, -158, 180, 10000, 10000, -330, -170, -300, -170); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 2) { 
                resetItems(12, 0, 226, 315, 420, 300, 520, 144, 520, 96, 10000, 10000, 615, 115, 605, 115); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 3) { 
                resetItems(-450, -300, -330, 200, 150, -70, -230, -156, -230, -204, 10000, 10000, -330, -170, -300, -170); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 4) { 
                resetItems(12, 0, 606, 120, 420, 100, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 410, 344, 320, 330, 320, 300); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 5) { 
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -72, -332, 200, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, -137, 130, 150, -70, 100, -70);//mite be -115 n 300, 200 , 100 
            } else if (countForLevels == 6) { 
                resetItems(12, 0, 130, 505, 250, 110, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 410, 300, 615, 215, 605, 215); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 7) { 
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -175, -50, 200, -98, 228, -98, 180, 10000, 10000, -130, -170, -100, -170); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 8) { 
                resetItems(12, 0, 606, 215, 620, 425, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 520, 465, 620, 525, 660, 525); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 9) { 
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -175, 150, -170, -28, 228, -28, 180, 10000, 10000, -40, -40, -20, -40); 
            } 
            lives--; 
        } 

        if (mQuatsch.collidesWith(mSpikesDown, true)) { 
           if (countForLevels == 1) { 
                resetItems(-450, -300, -40, 40, 150, -70, -50, 228, -158, 180, 10000, 10000, -330, -170, -300, -170); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 2) { 
                resetItems(12, 0, 226, 315, 420, 300, 520, 144, 520, 96, 10000, 10000, 615, 115, 605, 115); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 3) { 
                resetItems(-450, -300, -330, 200, 150, -70, -230, -156, -230, -204, 10000, 10000, -330, -170, -300, -170); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 4) { 
                resetItems(12, 0, 606, 120, 420, 100, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 410, 344, 320, 330, 320, 300); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 5) { 
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -72, -332, 200, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, -137, 130, 150, -70, 100, -70);//mite be -115 n 300, 200 , 100 
            } else if (countForLevels == 6) { 
                resetItems(12, 0, 130, 505, 250, 110, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 410, 300, 615, 215, 605, 215); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 7) { 
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -175, -50, 200, -98, 228, -98, 180, 10000, 10000, -130, -170, -100, -170); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 8) { 
                resetItems(12, 0, 606, 215, 620, 425, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 520, 465, 620, 525, 660, 525); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 9) { 
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -175, 150, -170, -28, 228, -28, 180, 10000, 10000, -40, -40, -20, -40); 
            } 
            lives--; 
        } 

        // what to do if a player hits a key 
        if (mQuatsch.collidesWith(mKey, true)) { 
            mKey.setVisible(false); 
            System.out.println(keys); 
            keys = keys + 1; 
            setPoints(getPoints() + 50); 
            System.out.println(keys); 
        } 

        // what to do if the player hits a monster 
        if (mQuatsch.collidesWith(mMonster, true)) { 
            if (countForLevels == 1) { 
                resetItems(-450, -300, -40, 40, 150, -70, -50, 228, -158, 180, 10000, 10000, -330, -170, -300, -170); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 2) { 
                resetItems(12, 0, 226, 315, 420, 300, 520, 144, 520, 96, 10000, 10000, 615, 115, 605, 115); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 3) { 
                resetItems(-450, -300, -330, 200, 150, -70, -230, -156, -230, -204, 10000, 10000, -330, -170, -300, -170); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 4) { 
                resetItems(12, 0, 606, 120, 420, 100, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 410, 344, 320, 330, 320, 300); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 5) { 
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -72, -332, 200, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, -137, 130, 150, -70, 100, -70);//mite be -115 n 300, 200 , 100 
            } else if (countForLevels == 6) { 
                resetItems(12, 0, 130, 505, 250, 110, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 410, 300, 615, 215, 605, 215); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 7) { 
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -175, -50, 200, -98, 228, -98, 180, 10000, 10000, -130, -170, -100, -170); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 8) { 
                resetItems(12, 0, 606, 215, 620, 425, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 520, 465, 620, 525, 660, 525); 
            } else if (countForLevels == 9) { 
                resetItems(-450, -300, -332, -175, 150, -170, -28, 228, -28, 180, 10000, 10000, -40, -40, -20, -40); 
            } 
            lives--; 
        } 

        if (isShown()) { 
            int keyStates = getKeyStates(); 
            if ((keyStates & LEFT_PRESSED) != 0) { 
                setDirection(kLeft); 
                movingCharacter(kRunning, 10, 0, -10, 0); 

            } else if ((keyStates & RIGHT_PRESSED) != 0) { 
                setDirection(kRight); 
                movingCharacter(kRunning, -10, 0, 10, 0); 

            } else if ((keyStates & UP_PRESSED) != 0) { 
                movingCharacter(kRunningUp, 0, 10, 0, -10); 

            } else if ((keyStates & DOWN_PRESSED) != 0) { 
                movingCharacter(kRunningDown, 0, -10, 0, 10); 

            } else { 
                setState(kStanding); 
                mCoin.nextFrame(); 
                mCoin2.nextFrame(); 
            } 

            frameCount++; 
            if (frameCount % factor == 0) { 
                int delta = 1; 
                if (frameCount / factor < 10) { 
                    delta = -1; 
                } 
                mAtmosphere.move(delta, 0); 
                if (frameCount / factor == 20) { 
                    frameCount = 0; 
                } 

                mBackground.setAnimatedTile(mAnimatedIndex, 
                        8 + animatedDelta++); 
                if (animatedDelta == 3) { 
                    animatedDelta = 0; 
                } 
            } 

            g.setColor(0x5b1793); 
            g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h); 

            mLayerManager.paint(g, 0, 0); 

            flushGraphics(); 
        } 

        try { 
            Thread.sleep(80); 
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) { 
        } 

        if (lives == 0) { 
            stop(); 
            g.drawImage(gameOver,10,50,Graphics.TOP | Graphics.LEFT); 
            repaint(); 
        } 

        if(countForLevels == 10){ 
            stop(); 
            g.drawImage(youWin,10,50,Graphics.TOP | Graphics.LEFT); 
            repaint(); 
        } 
    } 
    //String pointsString = Integer.toString(points); 
    //String levelString = Integer.toString(level); 

    //mScoreListener.collectItems(pointsString, levelString); 

    System.out.println("Points = " + getPoints() + "\nLevel = " + currentLevel); 
} 

public void movingCharacter(int state, int x, int y, int a, int b) { 
    setState(state); 
    mBackground.move(x, y); 
    mCollisionBackground.move(x, y); 
    mCollisionDoor.move(x, y); 
    mAtmosphere.move(x, y); 
    mCoin.move(x, y); 
    mCoin2.move(x, y); 
    mStairs.move(x, y); 
    mMonster.move(x, y); 
    mKey.move(x, y); 
    mQuatsch.nextFrame(); 
    mCoin.nextFrame(); 
    mCoin2.nextFrame(); 
    mSpikesUp.move(x, y); 
    mSpikesDown.move(x, y); 
    // if the player hits a wall 
    if (mQuatsch.collidesWith(mCollisionBackground, true)) { 
        mBackground.move(a, b); 
        mCollisionBackground.move(a, b); 
        mCollisionDoor.move(a, b); 
        mAtmosphere.move(a, b); 
        mCoin.move(a, b); 
        mCoin2.move(a, b); 
        mStairs.move(a, b); 
        mKey.move(a, b); 
        mMonster.move(a, b); 
        mSpikesUp.move(a, b); 
        mSpikesDown.move(a, b); 
    } 
    // if the user hits a door with a key and without a key 
    if (mQuatsch.collidesWith(mCollisionDoor, true)) { 
        if (keys > 0) { 
            System.out.println("hit wall with key" + doorMap[0][34]); 
            //doorMap[0][34] = 0; 
            mCollisionDoor.setVisible(false); 
            keys--; 
            mLayerManager.append(mCollisionDoor); 
            //mLayerManager.remove(mCollisionDoor); 
            setPoints(getPoints() + 10); 
            System.out.println("hit wall with key after changes" + doorMap[0][34]); 
        } else { 
            System.out.println("hit wall without key"); 
            mBackground.move(a, b); 
            mCollisionBackground.move(a, b); 
            mCollisionDoor.move(a, b); 
            mAtmosphere.move(a, b); 
            mCoin.move(a, b); 
            mCoin2.move(a, b); 
            mStairs.move(a, b); 
            mMonster.move(a, b); 
            mKey.move(a, b); 
            mSpikesUp.move(a, b); 
            mSpikesDown.move(a, b); 
        } 
    } 
} 

public void resetItems(int bg_x, int bg_y, int s_x, int s_y, int k_x, int k_y, int su_x, int su_y, int sd_x, int sd_y, int m_x, int m_y, int c_x, int c_y, int c2_x, int c2_y) { 
    mBackground.setPosition(bg_x, bg_y); 
    mCollisionBackground.setPosition(bg_x, bg_y); 
    mCollisionDoor.setPosition(bg_x, bg_y); 
    mStairs.setPosition(s_x, s_y); 
    mKey.setPosition(k_x, k_y); 
    mSpikesUp.setPosition(su_x, su_y); 
    mSpikesDown.setPosition(sd_x, sd_y); 
    mMonster.setPosition(m_x, m_y); 
    mCoin.setPosition(c_x, c_y); 
    mCoin2.setPosition(c2_x, c2_y); 
} 

public void stop() { 
    mTrucking = false; 

} 



public void setVisible(int layerIndex, boolean show) { 
    Layer layer = mLayerManager.getLayerAt(layerIndex); 
    layer.setVisible(show); 
} 

public boolean isVisible(int layerIndex) { 
    Layer layer = mLayerManager.getLayerAt(layerIndex); 
    return layer.isVisible(); 
} 

private void setDirection(int newDirection) { 
    if (newDirection == mDirection) { 
        return; 
    } 
    if (mDirection == kLeft) { 
        mQuatsch.setTransform(Sprite.TRANS_MIRROR); 
    } else if (mDirection == kRight) { 
        mQuatsch.setTransform(Sprite.TRANS_NONE); 
    } 
    mDirection = newDirection; 
} 

  public static int getPoints() { 
    return points; 
} 

/** 
 * @param aPoints the points to set 
 */ 
public static void setPoints(int aPoints) { 
    points = aPoints; 
} 

private void setState(int newState) { 
    if (newState == mState) { 
        return; 
    } 
    switch (newState) { 
        case kStanding: 
            mQuatsch.setFrameSequence(kStandingSequence); 
            mQuatsch.setFrame(0); 
            break; 
        case kRunning: 
            mQuatsch.setFrameSequence(kRunningSequence); 
            break; 
        case kRunningUp: 
            mQuatsch.setFrameSequence(kRunningSequenceUp); 
            break; 
        case kRunningDown: 
            mQuatsch.setFrameSequence(kRunningSequenceDown); 
            break; 
        case kCoinSpin: 
            mQuatsch.setFrameSequence(kCoinSpinning); 
            break; 
        case kMonsterMoveUp: 
            mMonster.setFrameSequence(kMonsterUp); 
            break; 
        case kMonsterMoveDown: 
            mMonster.setFrameSequence(kMonsterDown); 
            break; 
        default: 
            break; 
    } 
    mState = newState; 
} 

private void setDragonState(int newState) { 
    if (newState == dState) { 
        return; 
    } 
    switch (newState) { 
        case kStanding: 
            mMonster.setFrameSequence(kStandingSequence); 
            mMonster.setFrame(0); 
            break; 
        case kMonsterMoveUp: 
            mMonster.setFrameSequence(kMonsterUp); 
            break; 
        case kMonsterMoveDown: 
            mMonster.setFrameSequence(kMonsterDown); 
            break; 
        default: 
            break; 
    } 
dState = newState;
```

}

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but this is offtopic. See the FAQ: "To the best of your knowledge, does the code work?" It doesn't work, so it should be on StackOverflow.

Comment: ya the code works, it runs fine when i take out second coin and the sound, but when i put them in it works only up to level 3 and then it throws this error

Comment: Questions belong here if you want feedback on your code. If you want help fixing your code, it belongs on Stack Overflow, were I've now migrated this question.

Answer (score 0):

It's the LayerManager that is getting "full".

Between each level, I suggest to clear / empty it  by using the remove(int layer) method.